# Sending SMS from BlackBerry Simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I'm developing a BlackBerry Application where I should send Text SMS from BlackBerry Device.
As I'm new to Blackberry, started few days back I'm unable to proceed.

Can anyone Help with providing code snippets for send SMS from BlackBerry Device or Simulator?

Thanks in Advance.

Suresh.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void sendSMS(final String no, final String msg) {
    // try {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            boolean smsSuccess = false;
            if (RadioInfo.getNetworkType() == RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA) {


                DatagramConnection dc = null;
                try {
                    dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + no);
                    byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
                    Datagram dg = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());
                    dg.setData(data, 0, data.length);
                    dc.send(dg);
                    // / send successfully
                    smsSuccess = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception 1 : " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    smsSuccess = false;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        dc.close();
                        dc = null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception 2 : " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                MessageConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = (MessageConnection) Connector
                            .open("sms://" + no);
                    TextMessage tmsg = (TextMessage) conn
                            .newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
                    tmsg.setAddress("sms://" + no);
                    tmsg.setPayloadText(msg);
                    conn.send(tmsg);
                    smsSuccess = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    smsSuccess = false;
                    System.out.println("Exception 3 : " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                        conn = null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception 4 : " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(smsSuccess)
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Dialog.alert("success");
                    }
                }); 
            }else
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Dialog.alert("failure");
                    }
                }); 

            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Check out the the above code function .... to send SMS from Blackberry

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what language you are developing in, but if you are developing in java and, if you are using Eclipse for your development with the Blackberry Java plugins, you will find a wealth of sample applications in the plugins folder hierarchy. The actual location will depend on where you have installed Eclipse, but e.g. on my machine they are at: C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse 3.6.2 BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.33\components\samples\com\rim\samples\device for the OS7 samples. Similar samples will exist for the different OS plugins you have installed.

There is a long standing sample in most OS sample sets called smsdemo which should give you all the code you need. Even if you are not developing in java, this sample should give you an indication of the path you need to take to fulfil your requirement.